# Problem in Getting the row information of table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table and I want to grab the information of each row when they are clicked.

But when I click on first row,i got the information while doing  console.log(myArray[a]); but when i suddenly click 2nd row then onclick event is not trigerred.Since the 2nd row also has class 'box', i am not getting any information of this row in console.

```js
window.onload=build;
        var myArray=['suju','ruju','bhawana'];
var el=document.getElementById('message');

    function build(){
        var html="<h1>My friend list</h1><table>";
        for(var x=0;x<myArray.length;x++){
            html +='<tr data-row="'+x+'"><td>'+myArray[x]+'</td><td class="box" >'+(x+1)+'</td><td></td></tr>';
        }
        html +='</table>';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=html;

        var ek=document.querySelectorAll('#output .box');
        var a;
        for(var i=0;i<ek.length;ek++){
            ek[i].onclick=function(){
              a=this.parentElement.getAttribute('data-row');
                console.log(myArray[a]);
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
td{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <div id="message">Comple JS</div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the 2nd row and 3rd row's onclick function not trigerred?

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<ek.length;ek++)` you are incrementing `ek`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for(var i=0;i<ek.length;ek++){` you are not incrementing i here, rather, `ek`, the array itself, which would have no effect.

Instead, replace the ending of the for loop with i++.

Alternatively you can use an array's forEach function which may be simpler, `Array.apply(0, ek).forEach(x => /*code here*/);`

Comment: can u please also tell me where i can see .getAttribute() function. I did console.dir(this); but i didnot see any getAttribute() function? how can i know there is getAttribute function?